# safely editing the content of firefox jar file

Tags: firefox

i want to edit the content of browser.jar in my debian install to change the position of a button in firefox

*(if you need the "why": after a crash, the restore session screen has the buttons in a way that I always press "start new session" instead of restore... i don't know why... maybe my cancel-button-blidness just makes my brain think the long-text-button on the left is the confirm-action and the short text on the right is the cancel. ...instead of fighting with my dumb brain every time, i will move the button further down the screen or plain remove it)*

I've already extracted the contents with `unzip` and found the file I need to change `content/browser/aboutSessionRestore.xhtml`

the question, can I just do the changes, zip it again and i'm done? Or is there a little more info in a jar file than a zip archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dumb question. should have tried it right away.

this did the trick
`7z a browser.jar skin/ content/`

```
$ file browser.jar  /usr/share/iceweasel/chrome/browser.jar 
browser.jar:                             Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
/usr/share/iceweasel/chrome/browser.jar: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```